# how to set file attributes(1644) to a particular file using c++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, file, chmod

I want to create a file using c++ in linux with particular file permissions(1644).I know i can achieve this with chmod but I want to do it programatically via c++.

Is this possible?Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to retrieve the permissions, then use [chmod(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) to change them.

More generally, to understand what syscalls are done by some (command-line) program (e.g. `/bin/chmod`...), use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use struct stat in sys/stat.h

man 2 stat to see the various st_mode field values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chmod function from sys/stat.h:

```
int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

So something like:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
...
if (!chmod("/tmp/testfile",
        S_ISVTX |   // Sticky bit
        S_IRUSR | // User read
        S_IWUSR | // User write
        S_IRGRP | // Group read
        S_IROTH   // Other read
        ))
{
    // Handle error case
}
```